# DFP and HTML ads

Tags: html, google-dfp, double-click-advertising

I am new to DFP and having some trouble. I have built a basic html ad from scratch and am hosting it on my server. Now I need to send my ad company a script tag for them to insert as a third party creative. Could anyone run me through the process of this? I have been researching and understand it's to do with macros and click tracking but I am confused as to what code needs to go into my HTML files to get this all to work and how this links to the third party snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be sent as a third party, you should host your ad on your server and probably send them an iFrame of it.

The other option is to pack it as a ZIP and send it as an HTML5 creative. See the requirements here:
https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/7042362?hl=en